# Can you have a terminal file in Linux like windows Batch? What is the extension?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, bash-scripting

It has been a while since I downloaded my Kali Linux on a Windows virtual machine (VirtualBox not VMware). On my Windows host I have created numerous batch scripts that can execute "cmd code" with a `.bat` file extension. I was wondering if you could do the same for Linux terminals with e.g. a `.bash` file extension or something, or just execute a `.txt` file?. I have searched about the whole web, even stackexchange sites and quora, and found nothing.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31760/file-extensions-for-unix-shell-scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux equivalent of batch scripts are [shell scripts](https://www.shellscript.sh/) and usually have the extension `.sh` or no extension at all.

Linux does not depend on file extensions unlike Windows. Instead it uses file modes where a Shell script should be executable which is done with the command: `chmod +x filename`.

Although not required it is common to see shell scripts having the `.sh` extension.

The most common ways to run a shell script is with `./filename` from the same directory as the script or `/full/path/to/filename` from another directory.

Comment: It is quite common for shell scripts to have no extension at all: it is probably more true to to say that if a script has an extension it is usually `.sh`, but there is no requirement for this - all that is needed is that a text file is executable. An arbitrary executable text file will be treated as a shell script unless its first line is `!#` with the path to the program to handle the file, eg `#!/usr/bin/python` to run a Python script. The `file` utility shows the type of any file, and how Linux handles files is independent of any extension, though some applications may use them.

Comment: Although `bash` is [now] the most common Linux shell, and the probable default, there are other possibilities, so I would consider 'shell scripts' a more correct term than 'bash scripts'.

Comment: While I agree it's common not to have an extension on scripts I also think it's a pretty bad practice. Since the question was about what file extension they have I still think my answer is valid.

Comment: Actually, *having* an extension is bad practice. The user doesn't care if your command is implemented in Python or shell or C or whatever, and having to change every script which calls this script if you change the implementation language is just stupid.

Comment: Looking around I actually cannot find a clear definition for best practices, but for my daily work having an extension for helper scripts in my git repositories is definitely preferred to not having it. I see your point and I also see most (if not all) native scripts have no extension. I'll update the answer.